# Internal name for "Scheduled" List in Reminders App on iOS

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone, reminders

I try to connect [Do Note](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/do-note-by-ifttt/id905998379?mt=8) with the iOS Reminders app and add a new Button to add Reminders to the "Scheduled" List but everytime I try to create a Note from **Do Notes** I get a new list in the Reminders app called "Scheduled" and it won't add it to the internal "Scheduled" list (which shows up in the Notification center and sends push notification when a scheduled reminder comes up).

So my question is: What is the internal name for the "Scheduled" list in the Reminders app, so that I can add a Reminder from **Do Notes**

Btw: I am using iOS in german so the german name for the Scheduled list is "Planmäßig" but even with this name set up in Do Notes it won't add it to the correct list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Scheduled" list in Reminders is just all of the reminders that have a due date. There is no way to add a reminder to that list.

If you do use the + and add a reminder, you'll see it shows up on another list (Reminders list for me).

Comment: Ah! You're right! If you set a scheduled Time in another list it will show up in scheduled and in the notification center. I always thought it is a separate list but I just saw that it took the default list for storing the Reminder.